# What issues are there when content-type not sent in http?

Tags: http

What issues are there when content-type not sent in an httpresponse header?  Specifically what happens to JSON types like the one below if content_type is omitted?

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
"""
An HttpResponse that renders its content into JSON.
"""
def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)
```

Comment: then the webserver will guess and set a default type, and/or the client is free to GUESS what the type is. the data will still be transferred, but may not be handled the way you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to HTTP spec content-type **should** be passed as one of the headers, there is no "default value". If the client does not implement it - it's up to the server's implementation to decide what to return in the response. See last section of [7.2.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1)

Comment: that means it's best to include content-type always.

Comment: Indeed it does :)